# copy 2 lines of multiple files

Tags: shell, sed, awk

In a folder, I have several files with several parameters in their name. I should copy 2nd and last line of all these files to another one. The following command does the job for one file (1st sed copies 2nd line and the 2nd sed is related to the last line. tail command because I need to find the last generated file) :

```
(sed -n '2p' $(ls -rt1 pa*p3.3_*.txt | tail -1) && sed -n '$p' $(ls -rt1 pa*p3.3_*.txt | tail -1)) >> f1.txt
```

Now parameter p is in the range of e.g 1,1.1,1.2 .., 2.9,3. How can I perform the above command in a loop by shell? I have tried with the following script but does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=$(awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=3;i+=0.1)print i}')
for n in $num
do
  (sed -n '2p' $(ls -rt1 pa*p$n_*.txt | tail -1) && sed -n '$p' $(ls -rt1 pa*p$n_*.txt | tail -1))
done
```

How can I do this task? in general, how to perform commands, in a loop? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

not clear to me but 2nd and last line copied to a  file could simply be done by

```
sed -n '2p;$p' ListOfYourFiles > f1.txt
```

for the list of files we need a bit more specification to have an efficient sed/awk/script

Comment: good point, I forgot that I could copy both lines simultaneously! But my question was about how to do in a loop which I found out one has just to put as ${n} instead of $n in the sed command inside loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -sne '2w file3' -e '$w file3' file1 file2
```